Как решить вопрос пробелов и русских букв в имени файла?
С помощью Image Uploader (для Windows) выгружаю по FTP (на свой сервер vsFTPd) разные файлы в подкаталог, где находится папка домена, который управляется на одном сервере с помощью nginx. Сервер на Debian 12.
И когда выгружается файл с пробелами, то наблюдаю, что они заменяются нижним подчёркиванием.
Image Uploader после выгрузки выдаёт автоматически URL. Например
https://mysite.com/imgupl/iu/953790755_%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80.html

Где число до подчёркивания это рандомный ID, остальное слово Деинсталлятор, согласно URI.
Соответственно файл при попытке скачать, выдаёт 404, потому что на диске файл с подчёркиванием и нормальной кириллицей.
Вопрос - как сделать, чтобы nginx принимал файлы, как есть? Или хотя бы перекодированными в URI.
Конфиги чистил практически до нуля. Хотя у меня и там минимальный набор в 5 строчек.

А тупо сделать файлам нормальные имена большая проблема?

В apache русские символы превращаются при выгрузке в такое "Р”РµРёРЅСЃС‚Р°Р»Р»СЏС‚РѕСЂ".  - Тут не понятно, что вы имеете в виду под "В apache русские символы превращаются"?

Просто не используйте такие символы в именах файлов

@DiD, не смешно. От слова совсем.
Выгружаться может что угодно - изображения, pdf файлы, видео, текстовые ...
Мне сотни тысяч файлов сделать нормальными? Даже если и сделаю, удобство пользования локально приводит к такому себе развлечению.

@DiD, по поводу превращения. Ну вроде описал. Но ещё раз в деталях. Есть файл "Деинсталлятор.html", я его выгружаю на сервер по FTP с помощью обозначенной программы. В ней я получаю ссылку, которая "превращает" русские символы в унифицированный стандарт URI, то бишь кодирует символы. Смотрю в каталог на сервере, куда выгрузилось, там кракозябры. И эта папка лежит в домене, который управляется apache, поэтому так. Да, может я и ошибаюсь и это не apache, но тогда что? Если на другом сервере, который управляется nginx, всё нормально с русскими символами.

@ПростойЧеловек,
Дык используйте другую программу для загрузки, которая будет сохранять оригинальные имена файлам. Их же вагон и маленькая тележка. Тот же FileZilla умеет работать с FTP-серверами.

@ПростойЧеловек Мне сотни тысяч файлов сделать нормальными? - Не понимаю, какая разница какое количество файлов, если делается это одной командой в терминале?

@DiD среди тысяч этих программ только единицы, если не одна максимально удобна. А удобна тем, что два клика и всё что нужно уже готово. При этом быстро. Вот есть разница - сделать два клика и ссылка готова или запусти программу, сделай коннект, загрузи файл, закрой программу, сделай ссылку вручную. А в случае скриншотов, можно закачать не просто ссылку, а в виде таблицы с миниатюрами, которые отображаются миниматюрами, а по клику становятся полными. В общем понятно, что всё можно сделать другими, но насколько это удобно? Совсем не удобно.

@DiD да, одной командой в терминале, но сколько всего это поломает локально. Ладно, когда у тебя ничего или минимум подвязано на всё это дело. А когда оно годами настраивалось, то не вижу веской  причины, когда всё может работать и так. Проверено, потому что пользовался автоматизированными системами до этого, по типу ISP Manager.

@DiD и почему IU не нормально это делает? Ссылку то с точки зрения логики правильную формирует. Другое дело, что уже приложение на сервере обрабатывает по своей логике. Вот и вопрос, как изменить эту логику.

@ПростойЧеловек среди тысяч этих программ только единицы, если не одна максимально удобна, ну если у вас минутная задача затягивается на несколько дней, ради этих двух удобных кликов, то мне вас жаль. У меня например для запуска развертывания никаких кликов делать не надо.

@ПростойЧеловек почему IU не нормально это делает? - а почему на клавиатуре нет такой клавиши загрузить все картинки на сервер по протоколу FTP? Очевидно же, не может такого быть, чтобы на каждую хотелку было по своей кнопке.

@DiD жаль не жаль, мне тоже многих жаль.
Кнопки, мышки ... При чём здесь клавиши? Ноги, руки, главное хвост.
По делу есть что?

@ПростойЧеловек так я и пишу по делу. У вас есть общая задача "как залить на сервер много файлов?". И вы почему-то решили, что некая проприетарная программа решает вашу задачу, но решает её как-то неправильно. И теперь вы боретесь с последствиями работы этой программы, с которыми обычно другие люди вообще никогда не сталкиваются. А всё потому, что у вас нет понимания работы "регулярных выражений". Хотя в повседневной работе они нужны везде, поэтому они есть во всех языках программирования, в каждом текстовом редакторе (напр. блокнот). Если бы вы знали как их использовать, проблемы бы не было.

@DiD А мне вот жаль тебя, что ты не можешь въехать, в чём суть дела.

@ПростойЧеловек да я сразу понял суть проблемы. Здесь про это хорошо написано: Ошибка XY. Вот про микроскоп и гвозди - именно ваш вариант.

@ПростойЧеловек Вместо того, чтобы просто закачать файлы на сервер, вы используете проприетарную программу, чтобы разгребать последствия её действий. У этой программы 2.5 пользователя. А на SO среди таких пользователей - только вы. Почему вы не хотите связаться с её автором? Неужели сложно переименовать файл используя URL-safe characters 0123456789abcdefghIjklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ$–_.+!*‘(),?

Да я уже понял, что у тебя спрашивать не стоит.


Вопрос - как сделать, чтобы nginx или apache (хотя бы одно из двух)
принимал файлы, как есть?

Он и принимает "как есть". Просто никакой кириллицы в урлах не существует.

В apache русские символы превращаются при выгрузке в такое
"Р”РµРёРЅСЃС‚Р°Р»Р»СЏС‚РѕСЂ" Т

Это проблемы с перекодированием. Имена файлов написаны win-1251, а аппач выдаёт в UTF8.

Или хотя бы перекодированными в URI.

Для этого нужно файлы загружать через php-скрипт (или что-то подобное), который будет этим заниматься (транслитерировать).
А вообще лучше обзавестись правильной привычкой давать файлам названия в латинице без пробелов.

А что по поводу пробелов? Как отключить такое поведение на nginx или apache?

@ПростойЧеловек почитай по ссылке, изучай матчасть. (а я даже не знаю какая у тебя цель)

Цель - закачивать файлы (но в основном картинки) и постить на форумах.

те кто указываею на матчасть, как показывает практика - значит просто не знают ответа.
